# How to make a DIV expand up instead of down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On hovering a div, it should pop over the background-image above and show additional text. In addition, the background-image changes.

At the moment the DIV seems to only want to expand downward, but I really would like it to expand upward. But here is the kicker, I can not use `position: fixed` because the element needs to scroll with the page and not stick to the bottom.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
  $('#hover-01').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)');
  });
  $('#hover-01').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4)');
  });

  $('#hover-02').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)');
  });
  $('#hover-02').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4)');
  });

  $('#hover-03').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)');
  });
  $('#hover-03').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4)');
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#hover-change {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #f06d06;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white 50%, #333 50%, #333);
  background-size: 100% 202%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -150px;
  overflow: hidden;


}

.box h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box h3 {
  font: 0.8em "Lucida Grande", serif;
}

.box:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease;
  height: 400px;
}

.box:hover h2 {
  color: #48ad26;
}

.box:hover h2 span {
  color: white;
}

.box:hover h3 {
  color: #999;
}



.box2 {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white 50%, #333 50%, #333);
  background-size: 100% 202%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;


}

.box2 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box2 h3 {
  font: 0.8em "Lucida Grande", serif;
}

.box2:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease;
  height: 400px;
}

.box2:hover h2 {
  color: #48ad26;
}

.box2:hover h2 span {
  color: white;
}

.box2:hover h3 {
  color: #999;
}

.box3 {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white 50%, #333 50%, #333);
  background-size: 100% 202%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: 66%;
  overflow: hidden;


}

.box3 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box3 h3 {
  font: 0.8em "Lucida Grande", serif;
}

.box3:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease;
  height: 400px;
}

.box3:hover h2 {
  color: #48ad26;
}

.box3:hover h2 span {
  color: white;
}

.box3:hover h3 {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

</div>
<div class="responsive-section-image" id="hover-change">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a id="hover-01" class="open-project" href="#">
    <h2><span>Lunch -</span> is delicious anytime</h2>
    <h3>Even after dinner</h3>
    <p>
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <a id="hover-02" class="open-project" href="#">
    <h2><span>Lunch -</span> is delicious anytime</h2>
    <h3>Even after dinner</h3>
    <p>
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <a id="hover-03" class="open-project" href="#">
    <h2><span>Lunch -</span> is delicious anytime</h2>
    <h3>Even after dinner</h3>
    <p>
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
    </p>
  </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Would be easier if it was using the DRY principle. Should only be one .box class

Answer (score 6):

Another solution would be to use flexbox. This way you can make the items stick to the bottom of the container and make them "pop upwards" on hover.

Add `display:flex;` to the container element and `align-self:flex-end;` to the boxes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
   width:50%;
   height:80vh;
   display:flex;
}

.item {
   width:50%;
   height:30%;
   align-self:flex-end;
}

.item:hover {
   height:50%;
}
```

For a working example [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/dx953me0/)

Answer (score 1):

Because you know the exact height of the `.box` before and after its height expands, `translateY` for `-(difference in height)` to give the illusion that the `.box` is expanding upwards.

In other words, add this code on all `.box:hover`:

```
transform: translateY(-250px); // Or other difference in height
```

For your code, this is the result after I've added line of code on your `:hover`. I've also changed the height of `#hover-change` to `400px` simply because it cannot fit the whole `.box` expanding to `400px` upwards.

```js
$('#hover-01').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)');
  });
  $('#hover-01').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4)');
  });

  $('#hover-02').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)');
  });
  $('#hover-02').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4)');
  });

  $('#hover-03').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)');
  });
  $('#hover-03').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4)');
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#hover-change {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #f06d06;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white 50%, #333 50%, #333);
  background-size: 100% 202%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -150px;
  overflow: hidden;


}

.box h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box h3 {
  font: 0.8em "Lucida Grande", serif;
}

.box:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease;
  height: 400px;
  transform: translateY(-250px);
}

.box:hover h2 {
  color: #48ad26;
}

.box:hover h2 span {
  color: white;
}

.box:hover h3 {
  color: #999;
}



.box2 {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white 50%, #333 50%, #333);
  background-size: 100% 202%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;


}

.box2 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box2 h3 {
  font: 0.8em "Lucida Grande", serif;
}

.box2:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease;
  height: 400px;
  transform: translateY(-250px);
}

.box2:hover h2 {
  color: #48ad26;
}

.box2:hover h2 span {
  color: white;
}

.box2:hover h3 {
  color: #999;
}

.box3 {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white 50%, #333 50%, #333);
  background-size: 100% 202%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  animation: down-bump 0.4s ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: 66%;
  overflow: hidden;


}

.box3 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box3 h3 {
  font: 0.8em "Lucida Grande", serif;
}

.box3:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease;
  height: 400px;
  transform: translateY(-250px);
}

.box3:hover h2 {
  color: #48ad26;
}

.box3:hover h2 span {
  color: white;
}

.box3:hover h3 {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

</div>
<div class="responsive-section-image" id="hover-change">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a id="hover-01" class="open-project" href="#">
    <h2><span>Lunch -</span> is delicious anytime</h2>
    <h3>Even after dinner</h3>
    <p>
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <a id="hover-02" class="open-project" href="#">
    <h2><span>Lunch -</span> is delicious anytime</h2>
    <h3>Even after dinner</h3>
    <p>
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <a id="hover-03" class="open-project" href="#">
    <h2><span>Lunch -</span> is delicious anytime</h2>
    <h3>Even after dinner</h3>
    <p>
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
      test content test content
    </p>
  </a>
</div>

</div>
```

However, as the other person has pointed out in the comment section of your question, naming three elements with basically the same style differently is bad-practice. Look up DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

The </div> immediately after <div class="wrapper"> needs deleting because you have one too many closing div. Deleting this div will ensure that those 3 boxes are relative to the wrapper and when you scroll, so will the boxes despite using position:absolute.

Then this CSS will solve your problem

```
.box, .box2, .box3 {
   bottom : 0px;
}
```

The height is currently wrong in your hover CSS and will crop off the top, just adjust the value accordingly.